# Related Rates Problem - Water is being pumped into an inverted conical tank at an unknown constant rate.

Tags: calculus, related-rates

Water is leaking out of an inverted conical tank at a rate of 0.015 m³/min. At the same time water is being pumped into the tank at a constant rate. The tank has height 13 meters and the diameter at the top is 6.5 meters. If the water level is rising at a rate of 0.28 m/min when the height of the water is 5 meters, find the rate at which water is being pumped into the tank.

Comment: Hi Val, welcome to the Mathematics StackExchange!  You'll get a much better response if you explain what you've tried and where you get stuck, rather than only giving us an exercise to do.  People aren't going to want to just solve it for you, but if we know what you're having trouble with, then we can give you good advice.